# rows with highest weightage will considered

Tags: pandas, group-by

```py
details = {
    'Topic' : [0,0,0,0,
               1,1,1,
               3,3,3,
               4,4],
    'Word' : ['a', 'c', 'p', 'm', 
              'ad', 'a', 'p',
              's', 'm', 'rev',
              'rev', 'in'],
    'Weight' : [0.5,0.2,0.1,0.05,
                   0.2,0.1,0.06,
                   0.2,0.1,0.09,
                   0.2,0.1]
}
```

I tried this but how to add a topic column

```py
df.groupby('Weightage')(['Topic','Word']).max().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make groups on the basis of `Topic` instead of `Weight` which will return you *Word with highest weightage for each topic.*

Try:

```
df.groupby("Topic")[["Word","Weight"]].max().reset_index()
print(df)
```

```
  Topic Word    Weight
0   0   p        0.5
1   1   p        0.2
2   3   s        0.2
3   4   rev      0.2
```